# Can django-impersonate be used cross-origin?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I'm attempting to use django-impersonate with my django-rest based server.

The server is a pure REST server, and this is a fairly typical single-page app, so my statically-compiled JavaScript is hosted on a different server that's on another subdomain. However, it appears that django-impersonate cannot work cross-origin.

Here's my understanding of what is going on: when you attempt to call the impersonate endpoint, it does a redirect. However, the standard browser behavior is that cross-origin redirections strip off the "Authorization" header. Which kind of defeats the purpose of the endpoint.

Here's the error message I am getting:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://192.168.33.10:8000/impersonate/1/. Redirect from 'http://192.168.33.10:8000/impersonate/1/' to 'http://192.168.33.10:8000/accounts/login/?next=/impersonate/1/' has been blocked by CORS policy: Request requires preflight, which is disallowed to follow cross-origin redirect.
```

My question is whether there is any workaround for this. Since the django-impersonate package controls the endpoint, I can't manipulate the CORS headers myself, and to be honest I'm not even sure it would work if I could.

Comment: Did you manage to solve it somehow? I'm struggling with the same problem right now.

Comment: No, we abandoned this approach. Probably going to have to write our own home-grown impersonation system.